# finalescript select from dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, finalescript

How do you select an item from a list in finalescript?

I would like to transpose a certain piece of music by a perfect fifth without opening the dialog box. I know how to set radio buttons and type text, but how do you select a value from a dropdown list?

My code so far:

```
menu item "Utilities/Transpose..."
select "Perfect Fifth" from list //Does not work
press "OK"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found it.

From the documentation:

> Selecting an item from a List
>
> FinaleScript supports selecting from simple text-only lists. Simple
>   lists can be found in the Measure Number Regions dialog box,
>   Preferences dialog box, or Document Options dialog box.
>
> Note that most of Finale lists are not supported directly by
>   FinaleScript, including the following dialog boxes:Expression
>   Selection, Percussion Layout Selection, Articulation Selection, and
>   ScoreManager. The following commands are equivalent:
>
> select list "display colors"
>   list "display colors"

So, the code would be

```
menu item "Utilities/Transpose..."
select list "Perfect Fifth"
press "OK"
```